# How to avoid the higher expectations that come with seniority as well as any desire on the part of management to promote me?

Tags: promotion, vacation, lunch

I work for an organization that has a pay structure such that advancing beyond senior developer is utterly undesirable, but has excellent benefits and lots of vacation time and a strong stock market and savings from past jobs means that I can easily coast for the remainder of my career here. It funds a nice travel budget essentially and my wife still works so she thinks I should do something too.

However, I have a problem. I have become the most senior (by tenure) member of the team and the negative consequences of that are significant. People want me to take over the team lead position and keep pestering me about advancement and complaining that nobody wants the team lead job. Even when I turn it down, I am still hassled about taking the lead on topics and being essentially forced into doing a lot of the team lead work or covering for the product manager as "you know the domain better than they do."

- I do not wish to be considered a subject matter expert. That means more meetings, which I do not wish to be in. Unfortunately due to my being the longest serving developer on the team, people treat me like one and send me questions.
- I do not wish to teach or mentor new people. It is repetitive telling the rotating cast of players the same stuff over and over again.
- I do not wish to advance to leadership in any form. Not thought leadership. Not project management. Not providing advice. I have zero ambitions for anything beyond my current role.
- I do not wish for any form of accountability greater than that of a grunt worker responsible for churning out an average number of Jira tickets. I want to continue to sign off/leave at 5PM and have any downstream implications of that not be my problem. I also do not want to be expected to complete more story points than the other developers on the team.
- I do not wish to be the person they turn to in a urgent situation to find an urgent solution. I have so far managed to stay off the on-call rotation, but as team churn increases, I get badgered about that more (it is officially voluntary per company policy and I do not need the extra money) and team members will message me outside of work hours.
- I have no equity, and even if I did, I wouldn't really need it, so I have no stake whatsoever in the success or failure of the team or the department.

Basically, I want to stay on level and leverage my skills to continue working about 4 hours a week of actual work, as I do know the system best. The domain knowledge required is insane and even small changes bog down the other members of the team, so I can just read and watch Netflix while producing work at the same rate as the other devs. What steps should I take to seem unfit for anything beyond being an order taking code grunt?

Comment: Realistically, I don't think you can dodge "the needs of the business" and stay where you are; even if management understands your intent they're going to have to remote you or cut your pay because you _are_ underperforming by their standards. And the moment they decide they don't need you, you're gone on favor of spending the money on someone with more energy. "Retired In Place" tends to be bad for morale.

Comment: "**so I can just read and watch Netflix while producing work at the same rate as the other devs**"  Does your company allow this ?

Comment: -1 for nausea induction

Answer (score 1):

This presents an interesting problem.

My first thought would be to have a frank sit-down with your senior management and let them know these thoughts. I knew a guy that was in a similar situation - The only reason he came to work was because if he stayed at home he would (an I quote) "Drink and then become destructive" - so, he came to work, did his 9-5 to keep him out of trouble and much past that did not give a flying f.....udge.

In that case - the CEO of the company was well aware of why he was there, what value he brought to the team and that keeping him happy was in the best interests of everyone because he simply did not need the job.

You might have some luck with a similar conversation.

Next option would be to leave and go somewhere where you aren't the senior person, therefore no one is looking to you for leadership. It might result in a pay cut - but it sounds like Financially you are secure, you just want something to do. Get a job as a junior Dev - tell them exactly what you want to do, clock in, clock out - no pressure, just write some code and get on with it.

You could also look at contracting, just showing up as and when needed, charge a rate and then when all the other stuff that doesn't interest you gets bandied about... Leave. Put it into your contract that here is a bunch of stuff you have no interest in doing.

Answer (score -1):

You can tell you boss that you have some commitments outside work that require you to leave by 5 PM, and therefore, you can't handle lots of extra workload and responsibility.

Tell him you want to keep the same salary and the same title, and don't want any promotion.

**The tricky thing is that managers usually expect and prefer employees to grow and take on additional mentoring roles or even leadership over the time**.

Even if you say "I want to keep the same salary. So, don't give me additional tasks", the managers still think that you don't want to grow as an employee.

Also, please be mindful that if your salary happens to be higher than your level of contribution, then your boss may notice that in case a workforce reduction happens in the future.

---

Nowadays, there is a trendy term for this: “**quiet quitting**”.

A search on the web shows the following explanation: (Just google "quite quitting")

The term “**quiet quitting**” refers to employees who put no more effort into their jobs than absolutely necessary. A 2022 Gallup survey suggested that at least half of the US workforce consists of quiet quitters.

---

Therefore, we may need to create a new tag called “**quiet quitting**” for this site :-)

Comment: I am not a senior titled worker with a senior titled salary though. They want to make me one.

Comment: @DavidHays, OK, I updated the answer a bit.

Comment: @DavidHays, "**I want to stay on level and leverage my skills to continue working about 4 hours a week of actual work**". Did you only do the actual work for 4 hours ? What happens to the other 36 hours ? Or is it a typo and you meant to say "40 hours"  instead of "4 hours" ?

Comment: I think, as you've noticed, the "read and watch Netflix" passage is consistent with the "4 hours a week of actual work" really being 4 hours.

Comment: @Job_September_2020 only 4 hours of real work. Being an expert at the codebase and the tech allows for that. I know exactly what to do for most features.

Comment: @DavidHays generally, most employers consider that they are paying you for your *time*, not your work. So they expect you to actually work for whatever time you're being paid for. If you want to get paid for work done rather than time worked, you can become a freelancer.